# Delete request with body

Tags: retrofit

I'm using Retrofit and I want to make a request with tge delete method. I want to use a specific body, but the delete method doesn't support that. I created my custom class for delete method like this:

```
@Target(METHOD) 
@Retention(RUNTIME) 
@RestMethod( hasBody = true,value = "DELETE") 
public @interface CustomDelete {   

String value();      

 }
```

But when I use it I have this error:

```
10-31 16:24:09.459: I/System.out(21090): retrofit.RetrofitError: DELETE does not support writing
```

Answer (score 23):

Try this (with Retrofit 2.0):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "/api/resource/etc", hasBody = true)
Call<ApiResponse> deleteSomething(@Field("id") int id);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE",path="/api/v1/media/{username}/{accesstoken}", hasBody = true)
Call<MyResponse> deleteArchiveMedia(@Path("username") String username, @Path("accesstoken") String token  ,
                                    @Body DeleteMedia deleteMedia);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having a issue with the DELETE as well but a more basic one and found this discussion. It seems to me that it might answer your question.

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/426

My issue is, that whenever I define my interface it gives me a syntax error on METHOD and RUNTIME.
Do I need to include something somewhere to be able to use it?